# Can't run GraphX ConnectedComponents on spark 1.5.1 with large data (~4TB)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

While trying to run a spark job with spark 1.5.1, using the following paramters:

```
--master "yarn" 
--deploy-mode "cluster" 
--num-executors 200 
--driver-memory 14G 
--executor-memory 14G  
--executor-cores 1
```

Trying to run graphX ConnectedComponent on large data (~4TB) using the following commands:

```
System.setProperty("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
val edges = …
val graph = Graph.fromEdgeTuples(edges,0,edgeStorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK, vertexStorageLevel = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
val components = graph.connectedComponents().vertices
```

Some of the tasks complete successfully, and some fail with the following errors:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 2
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:456)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$.org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses(MapOutputTracker.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.getMapSizesByExecutorId(MapOutputTracker.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.hash.HashShuffleReader.read(HashShuffleReader.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and another error:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Connection from phxaishdc9dn1209.stratus.phx.ebay.com/10.115.60.32:40099 closed
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.EdgePartition.updateVertices(EdgePartition.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.ReplicatedVertexView$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ReplicatedVertexView.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.ReplicatedVertexView$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ReplicatedVertexView.scala:115)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from phxaishdc9dn1209.stratus.phx.ebay.com/10.115.60.32:40099 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:91)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
            ... 1 more
```

Please advise,
Thanks in advance,
Arnon

Comment: I think these exceptions are generally caused by losing executors. Do you see _"Executor lost"_ entries in the driver logs? The executor is generally lost due to out-of-memory conditions. (Check the logs of the lost executor.) The OOM is generally caused by too much data per partition or too many partitions.

Comment: What do you think should be done in this case ? which parameters should be changed and how ?

Comment: First you should understand what exactly is happening. Once you understand, the solution is often simple. If your partitions are too large, try smaller partitions for example. But at this point we don't even know if memory issues are the problem. It could be that YARN is killing your executors for some reason, in which case you need to adjust the configuration for YARN or for Spark. Until you look at the logs and figure out what happened there is no hope of fixing it by changing things.